# Shared Element Transition between RecyclerView and Toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, shared-element-transition

I want use a shared element transition from a `TextView` in my `RecyclerView` into the Toolbar. The `RecyclerView` lives in a `Fragment` and when I click one of the rows, the text becomes the title of the next page. I want to animate this transition. The `Toolbar` lives in the `Activity` that contains a fragment container `FrameLayout` where I swap fragments using `replace()`.

Comment: You're talking about using a transition without actually transitioning between anything, as far as your `Toolbar` is concerned. Create a layout that contains your `Toolbar` with a `TextView` for your title. Then either place that and set it up in each of your `Fragment` using SET or place it in your `Activity` on top of your fragments and then determine where to animate the title on your own using something like `View.getLocationInWindow`.